# Converting time from server to UTC time

Tags: javascript, date

I have a string `2013-04-29T14:26:59Z` and I want to convert it to `2013-04-29 14:26:59 UTC`. How would I do that, I've googled and tried some examples in my firebug console but I haven't managed to produce similar results.

I've tried suggestion from following posts as well :

[How do I convert a string to a UTC date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019991/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-utc-date)
[How to change the date format in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533344/how-to-change-the-date-format-in-jquery)

Is there are nicer way to achieve the desired output other that this :

```
dt = new Date('2013-04-29T14:26:59Z')

dt.getFullYear() + '-' + '0' +(dt.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-' + dt.getUTCDate() + ' ' + dt.getUTCHours() + ':' + dt.getUTCMinutes() + ':' + dt.getUTCSeconds() + ' UTC'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QLXHz/

Comment: it'd be nice if JS has a printf()-type date formatter, but nope. you're stuck with multiple method calls and string concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could try something like this:

```
function date_to_utc_string(date) { // rename as convenient :p
  var format = [["FullYear","-"],["Month","-"],["Date"," "],["Hours",":"],["Minutes",":"],["Seconds"," UTC"]],
    l = format.length, pad = function(x) {return (x<10?"0":"")+x;}, i, t, ret="";
  for(i=0; i<l; i++) {
    t = date["getUTC"+format[i][0]]();
    if( format[i][0] == "Month") t++;
    ret += pad(t)+format[i][1];
  }
  return ret;
}
```

This is a basic date formatter that only outputs that one format you were asking about.

With this function in place, all you have to do is call `date_to_utc_string(dt)` and you get the formatted string back.